# Testing AngularJS app with C backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, integration-testing

I'm working on an AngularJS app and now, when it comes to testing - I'm completely confused. And newbie. The biggest problem, I guess, will be integration testing - from internet I've learned that recommanded attitude is to use some e2e tools like protractor, but I don't think that will be possible - the problem is that I can't use nodejs - app runs on server written in C. I'm guessing I'll have to treat it as black box.

Do you guys have any experience with such cases?

Comment: is testing being done in a pipeline, locally, or with the use of two machines?

Comment: Your frontend tests shouldn't be testing the backend functionality. The backend should have its own separate set of tests. You can still have frontend unit tests, but whenever there is a backend call that needs to happen, simply mock it with the expected return value. After all, you aren't concerned with whether or not the backend is actually working in those tests. Besides protractor, look into karma, mocha, chai, sinon, etc...